# How to display images from a loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array of images and would like to display them in a div tag using a loop, but none of the images are showing.

```
const images = ["images/image1", "images/image2", "images/image3"];


            
for (let x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {
                    
    const element = '<img src="' + images[0] + '">'
    let pic = document.querySelector('.images').innerHTML += element;
    pic;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `pic` variable.

Comment: `images[0]` every time you read the first image. You should be using `x` which is the index of the array. `images[x]` Now if the images do not show up, then you have an issue with the path to the image.

Comment: You should move away from string creation / manipulation and instead create actual elements and append them. It is true that the document initially exists as HTML text, but the browser parses it into the DOM, and inserting elements into the DOM is much more convenient (and more performant) than adding together a bunch of strings with various quotes all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You are only ever referencing the first index of the array since you used `images[0]`. You should be using the index.

```js
const images = ["http://placekitten.com/200/300", "http://placekitten.com/100/300", "http://placekitten.com/400/300"];

for (let x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {            
    const element = '<img src="' + images[x] + '">'
    document.querySelector('.images').innerHTML += element;
}
```

```html
<div class="images"></div>
```

You you want to use innerHTML to add the images, using `map()` and `join()` would be a better solution since you only will update the DOM once.

```js
const images = ["http://placekitten.com/200/300", "http://placekitten.com/100/300", "http://placekitten.com/400/300"];


const myHtml = images.map(function(path) {
  return '<img src="' + path + '">';
}).join('');

document.querySelector('.images').innerHTML = myHtml;
```

```html
<div class="images"></div>
```

Other option is creating the elements and appending them.

```js
const images = ["http://placekitten.com/200/300", "http://placekitten.com/100/300", "http://placekitten.com/400/300"];

const outElem = document.querySelector('.images');

images.forEach(function (path) {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = path;
  outElem.appendChild(img);
});
```

```html
<div class="images"></div>
```

Comment: when I try this, I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: So that means it did not find your element....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const images = ["images/image1", "images/image2", "images/image3"];


            
for (let x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {
                    
    const element = '<img src="' + images[x] + '">'
    document.querySelector('.images').innerHTML += element;
   
}
```

Comment: `let element` should be `const`

Comment: @epascarello element willl be reassigned that's why I used `let`

Comment: It is defined in a block and value is not set again, it should be const

Answer (score 0):

Try `appendChild`:

```js
const images = ["images/image1", "images/image2", "images/image3"];
const container = document.querySelector('#images');
for (let image of images) {
  const htmlImage = document.createElement("img");
  htmlImage.src = image;
  container.appendChild(htmlImage);
}
```